# how retrive 20 the first word in mysql database with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

it's my data in mysql database :

**Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.**

I want 20 first words :

**Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy**

what is my query in codeigniter ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql retrieve partial column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887344/mysql-retrieve-partial-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the default codeigniter function:

$string = **character_limiter**($string, 400);

Answer (score 0):

Text helper has function called `word_limiter($str[, $limit = 100[, $end_char = '&#8230;']])` that is used just for that.
Check in [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/text_helper.html#word_limiter).